# ASP.net Usercontrol caching viewstate across users?

Tags: asp.net

I have a usercontrol with asp:textbox controls on it that also performs postbacks. If two users, who are both identified by a different session variable, postback the page within the same second, one user will see the other user's viewstate values in the text boxes. I have validated that this happens by setting a textbox, a session variable, and a cookie to the same value (the same value that identifies the user) and writing to the log when all three don't match. The text box's value is the one that is logged as the other user's value.

ASP.net 3.5, IIS 6

Has anyone experienced this issue.

Comment: Could you post a small piece of code that illustrates this?  The viewstate is actually passed as a hidden variable when posting back, so the issue probably lies elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The UserControl itself shouldn't be caching anything across users. You must be doing something with ViewState yourself to cause this - perhaps at a lower level, like when saving the viewstate to a DB (if you have custom code for that). You'd have to post all the relevant code for anyone to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Would i just ask the question again with the relative code? I'm new to this site. I know that my code is not modifying the viewstate, the only thrid party control involved in this is a RadTabStrip from Telerik. I know by design the .Net framework is not supposed to do this, but i was hoping that maybe there was someone that had already talked about this and that my google skills were just lacking. I found it odd that it only happens when transactions are within a single second.

Comment: You can just edit this question to add the code. Some code somewhere is probably using a timestamp as a cache key, with second resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a proxy server involved in the equation? I have seen this exact symptom where a proxy server was serving up cached pages from other users.

Comment: Funny you should mention that... at the very start of the .com revolution our main competitors launched their eC site a month or so before we did.  Of course we went right to the site to try it out, and ended up "sharing" a shopping cart for similar reasons (we shared the office IP and they used the IP as part of the session).  That was 1997.  You observed something like that recently?

Comment: It was a couple of years ago accessing an internal web app on on a clients multi site network. They were using proxies between sites to conserve WAN bandwidth.

Comment: Nope, no proxy server involved. I know this is not supposed to be happening, and all goes well until two users postback within less 1000 miliseconds. All standard .net server controls and a RadTabStrip.